# Please help me fix this IF statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I can't get this code to go through. What am I missing?

This is a new statement which is part of an internal database but I cannot get it to accept the code.

```
SELECT "Human Resources - Assignment EIT Details"."Employment Attributes"."Employee Latest Start Date", "Assignment"."Incremental Date"

CASE

WHEN "Assignment"."Incremental Date" IS NULL THEN "Human Resources - Assignment EIT Details"."Employment Attributes"."Employee Latest Start Date"
ELSE "Assignment"."Incremental Date" END;
```

I expect the output to show the Incremental Date but if the field IS NULL then it needs to show the Employee Latest Start Date

Comment: Typo? Add *comma* `,` after `"Assignment"."Incremental Date"` (before `case`): `... "Assignment"."Incremental Date", case ...`

Comment: Should there be a FROM statement? Which SQL?

Comment: That didnt work. I am getting this error - Invalid Alias Format : Table_name.Column_name required

Comment: It's an inhouse SQL so it doesnt follow a lot of the standard rules which makes it a bit hit and miss!

Comment: You use JOIN. Try to use aliases for your table names to make the query more readable

Comment: I know basic functions using JOIN but not sure how I create a CASE statement with a JOIN added in.

Comment: It's not different just because you have a CASE

Comment: Hi Joakim, please could you just show me an example of the code and then I can test it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay my new code is 

SELECT "Employment Attributes"."Employee Latest Start Date", "Assignment"."Incremental Date"

FROM "Human Resources - Assignment EIT Details"

CASE

WHEN "Assignment"."Incremental Date" IS NULL THEN "Employment Attributes"."Employee Latest Start Date"
ELSE "Assignment"."Incremental Date" END;

It still doesnt work. Please help.

Comment: SELECT a.col1, CASE WHEN a.col2 IS NULL THEN b.col1 ELSE a.col2 END FROM tableA a JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.other_id

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I have fixed it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code was ;

```
CASE WHEN "Human Resources - Assignment EIT Details"."Assignment"."Incremental Date" IS NULL 
THEN "Human Resources - Assignment EIT Details"."Employment Attributes"."Employee Latest Start Date" 
ELSE "Human Resources - Assignment EIT Details"."Assignment"."Incremental Date" 
END
```